# How to create new tab on magento product page step by step

Tags: create

Any one please tell me 
How to create new tab on magento product page step by step.

Comment: are you using custom theme?

Comment: have you tryied anything ?

Comment: yes i'm using custom theme

Comment: where in admin side or in frontend side ?

Comment: i have tryied lot many logic but its fail

Comment: frontside on product description page

Comment: what are you trying to add there? any attribute? static block?

Comment: can you please specify these things while you ask a question. Your question is not complete.

Comment: i'm trying to add custom tab on product description page.

Comment: i have purchase a theme there is only three tabs like Description, tags, review my question is how to add one more tab in it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/review.xml` layout update file. You can find a perfect example on how to add such tab. Below I am adding the relevant content.

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

Here `addToParentGroup` action is what doing the trick. What happens here is, it defines a block `product.reviews` and then add this block into parent block's `detailed_info` group. The parent block of `product.reviews` is `product.info` block. If you check out the `catalog.xml` you can find more group blocks definition for `product.info` block over there.

So what you need to do is, replicate the above layout update in the sameway in your layout update xml file. The only difference that you need to make here is, you need to define your own custom block (which you will use to show the tab content) and then add that block to `detailed_info` group. You are done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /layout/local.xml
search tab inside it. You can see something like this `<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>`

Duplicate it. Rename description to your desired one. Add corresponding support files in catalog/product/view/yourname.phtml and /code/core/Mage/Catalog/block/product/view/Yourname.php.

Also you need to change the content as well.